# Laravel Policy Ignoring View, Update, and Delete but Create works just fine

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, permissions

I'm creating my first Laravel policy. I have a basically fresh laravel 5.4 project that has a Project model. I've created one policy named ProjectPolicy but I'm having trouble getting all of the methods to work.

If I call `$user->can('create', Project::class)` I get the 'here' dump and it returns true. However the view, create, and delete actions never reach the ProjectPolicy. "here" is never dumped and false is always returned. I can't think of or find any reason why one policy method would work while the others do not. What am I missing?

App\Policies\ProjectPolicy.php

```
namespace App\Policies;

use App\User;
use App\Project;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class ProjectPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;


    /**
     * Determine whether the user has a specific ability for projects.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function before($user, $ability)
    {
        var_dump('here');
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the project.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function view(User $user, Project $project)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create projects.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the project.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function update(User $user, Project $project)
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can delete the project.
     *
     * @param  \App\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Project  $project
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function delete(User $user, Project $project)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

AuthServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use App\Project;
use App\Policies\ProjectPolicy;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * The policy mappings for the application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $policies = [
        Project::class => ProjectPolicy::class,
    ];

    /**
     * Register any authentication / authorization services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the logs for errors?

Comment: Just cleared out the log and ran all the `can` methods again. Nothing was logged.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely that you are calling `$user->can('view', Project::class)` without passing an instance of the project.  Try calling `$user->can('view', $project)` where $project is an instance of the project class for all those methods which require a project in their function definition.

Comment: 1) doing that throws an error, 2) I'm calling `$user->can('view', Project::first())` and there is only one project in my db. So should be fine?

Comment: I would dd(Project::first()); to determine what exactly you're passing to the function.

Comment: dd(Project::first()) = `App\project {#667
     id: 1,
     name: "My First Project",
     created_at: "2017-03-21 01:50:33",
     updated_at: "2017-03-21 01:50:33",
   }`

Comment: Did just notice that if I call `$user->can('view', Project::class)` The "here" is dumped out. So its only looking at the policy if I pass the wrong arguments in? Lol

Comment: The object you dumped out there seems fine other than that the Project class isn't capitalized.  I suspect that if you're not receiving any errors for this in the Laravel logs they're being included somewhere else (i.e. - base Apache logs, etc.).  You should be generating an error if there's some issue with the type of object passed to the function.  The next steps I would take are trying to locate any errors that may be generated in any pertinent log locations and attempting to dd($user, $project); within one of the functions to check whether it's hitting the function without before();

Comment: Wow, that capital P was the issue. Opened up App\Project and the class declaration was all lowercase. So I'm assuming it didn't recognize `Project::first()` as a Project model or something like that. Which makes sense why create worked an the others didn't. Good eye! Thanks